# Angular communication with back-end

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to create an authentication-service in angular in order to register/login users.

After registering a new user I have some trouble receiving the response to the service.

Here is the flow:

Front-end controller that passes the new user to the Auth-service:

```
vm.onSubmit = function () {
      Authentication
      .register(vm.credentials)  
        .then(function(){       
          $location.path('/');
        });
    };
```

The Authentication-services `register`-function

```
register: function(user) {
          return $http.post('/api/register', user).success(function(data){
          console.log('authserviceDONE'); //I never get back here...
          });
        },
```

The `api/register` -route

```
app.post('/api/register', function(req, res) {
        User.register(new User({ username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err,user) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json(err);
            }
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
                console.log(req.user); // User gets logged
            return req.user;
        });

        });
});
```

I am hoping to receive the user-object in the front-end in order to log him in to the app but the Auth-service never receives anything. Any tips on what I might be missing here?

Comment: Do you get any error message. Can you check browser network logs and see the request/response

Comment: I can only see the req I pass to the server. Containing the user-object. But nothing else...times-out after a while..

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how your project is structured so I am going to show you what works for me. I usually have three files: `app.js` `controllers.js` `services.js` - this is pretty standard.

Here is an example:

`app.js`

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services'])
.config(function (...) { ...
```

`controllers.js`

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, srvAccount, $log){

srvAccount.getaccount()
.then(
    function(response){
        $scope.account = response.data;
        $log.info(response.data);
    },
    function(rejection){
        $log.error("getaccount error");
        $log.log(rejection);
    }
);
...
```

and finally `services.js`

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.factory('srvAccount', function ($http) {
return {
    getaccount: function () {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/getaccount'
        });
    }
}
});
```

Have the browser developer tools > console open and use AngularJS `$log` to debug. More on `$log` here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log